# "This" type in generic parameter for derived classes

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to specify in type parameters that a parameter is the type of the object instance?

For instance, to illustrate, I have:

```
public abstract class Model
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

For my example, I want to have a method that will return a property of the `Model` passed in (obviously this is a stupid method, but it gets the point across). I can make it work as an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static U Property<T, U>(this T model, Expression<Func<T, U>> property) where T : Model
    {
        return property.Compile().Invoke(model);
    }
}
```

this way I can have

```
public class DerivedModel : Model
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

and do

```
var myString = new DerivedModel().Property(a => a.Prop2);
```

This method seems like it should be part of the `Model` class, and look something like:

```
public T Property<T>(Expression<Func<ThisDerivedInstanceOfModel, T>> property)
{
    return property.Compile().Invoke(this);
}
```

so that the same call to `Property()` that the extension method does can execute on an instance of a `Model`.

I realize that this is kind of bizarre and may simply not be a feature of C#, and the workaround extension method works perfectly well - but I'd much prefer to make this an instance method if possible, since seems 'better' to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify in type parameters that a parameter is the type of the object instance?

Nope. Sorry. There are times when I can see it being useful, but it's not something you can do. I've had similar issues in the past :(

Comment: Somehow I knew the first answer to this question would be Jon Skeet saying "no." Thanks!